# Android Wear flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

My app should have flavors (Play Store, Amazon, Samsung, Blackberry). As I think, only apps from the Play Store can use Android Wear, because of only this devices can use the Play Services. Now, I don't want to pack my Wear apk into every flavor with

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(':android-wear')
}
```

How can I do it only for the Play Store flavor? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `0.14.3` this is possible. Suppose your flavor for Google Play is called `google`, your `dependencies` entry would be called `googleWearApp`:

```
productFlavors {
    google {
    }
}
dependencies {
    googleWearApp project(':wear')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible at present (v0.12.2 of the Android Gradle plugin at the time I'm writing this). A feature request has been filed; you cant track it at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74658